# Passing values between Controllers and Views

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, controller

I am working within another person's project framework and my lack of experience with using an MVC is problematic. The controller's `index()` passes a value to its view via the `$data` variable, then the view has URLs which trigger other functions in the controller.

When one of these URLs is clicked, I need to get this value to the controller function that is being called. I don't want to pass it in the URL itself and I am wondering if there is any other good way to do so?

Example controller function I need to pass a value to:

```
public function ftp($request = null)
{
    $data['title'] = 'ftp';
    $data['page'] = 'services';
    \helpers\session::set('template', 'default');
    if (!Session::get('user'))
    {
        Url::redirect('');
    }
    else
    {
        $data['request'] = $request;
        $data['baseUrl'] = '/site/'.$request.'/';
        $this->view->render('site/ftp',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which framework?  there should be some form of router that maps the URLs to the controllers and therefor the controller functions and their arguments.

Comment: Never heard of it until now but its Simple MVC http://simplemvcframework.com/php-framework

Comment: I found the route file, just not sure of how to use it to accomplish this. I realize this question may be too generic, which I will just delete it if it is. Just very confused at the moment :)